# Blinq for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

While searching on google, I came acrross through BLinq, all I see is the articles dated on 2006. In one of the article I read that it doesn't have "Go Live" licence.
Does Microsoft still spport Blinq Prototype?
and why it is unsupported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blinq is retired, but look at [ASP.NET Dynamic Data Scaffolding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488540.aspx), this is a more recent tool from Microsoft, that is supported, to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No. I see that its retired. Microsoft does not directly support preview releases.

Comment: Will it be safe if I develop Blinq application for production database. I mean I afarid if it is retired because of false update of database or any other reason.

Comment: No. I would look at @joshcomley's suggestion or ASP.NET MVC.